# QR decomposition computational efficiency

Tags: matrix, computational-statistics, efficiency, qr-decomposition

I am struggling to find a reference for this: In terms of big Oh notation does anyone know of any expressions for the computational time taken by commonly used algorithms for QR decompositions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I've counted correctly, in general, QR decomposition on a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ should be $\mathcal{O}(d^2D)$ flops using the Householder method, where $D = \max\{m,n\}$ and $d = \min\{m,n\}$.

Why, the actual matrix $R$ in question is $R = H_K \cdots H_1 A$ where $K=\min\{m-1,n\}$ and each $H_k$ is a Householder matrix. However, multiplying $HB$ is relatively easy (compared to generic matrix multiplication) when $H = I - 2uu^T$.

Indeed, we can first compute $v = B^Tu$ in $\mathcal{O}(mn)$ flops.
Second, we can recover $2uu^TB$ as $M = 2uv^T$ in exactly $2mn$ multiplications. Finally, we just need to subtract $B-M$ in exactly $mn$ subtractions. Thus, the cost of computing the matrix product $HB$ is $\mathcal{O}(mn) + 2mn + mn = \mathcal{O}(mn)$.

We need to do this $K \leq d$ times (the $k$-th time using the already computed $B = H_{k-1}\cdots H_1 A$) hence the total complexity is $d\mathcal{O}(mn) = \mathcal{O}(dmn) = \mathcal{O}(d^2D)$ where the final equality holds upon noticing the cute fact that $mn = dD$.

The matrix $Q$ itself is just $Q=H_K \cdots H_1$. The flops required for computing this matrix can be counted by applying the previous reasoning, too.

Answer (score 6):

[Wikipedia says the complexity is $O(n^3)$ floating point multiplication operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) when using Householder reflections.

> The following table gives the number of operations in the $k$-th step of the QR-decomposition by the Householder transformation, assuming a square matrix with size $n$.
>
> $$\begin{array}{c|c|} 
>   \text{Operation} & \text{Number of operations in $k$th step} \\ \hline
> \text{Multiplications} & 2(n-k+1)^2  \\ \hline
> \text{Additions} & (n-k+1)^2 + (n-k+1)(n-k)+2  \\ \hline
> \text{Divisions} & 1 \\ \hline
> \text{Square Root} & 1 \\ \hline
> \end{array}$$
>
> Summing these numbers over the $n-1$ steps (for a square matrix of size $n$), the complexity of the algorithm (in terms of floating point multiplications) is given by
>
> $$
> \frac{2}{3}n^3 + n^2+\frac{1}{3}n-2=O(n^3)
> $$